# Drag 'N Drop Divs into other Divs

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to create draggable content divs that can be sorted into other divs on a page.  The problem is the Divs are user generated, so I won't know what the divs are called or how many divs there will be.

Basically, how can I sort divs across multiple divs and save that information to the database?  I know how to sort information inside one div, but not across multiple divs where I don't know how many or what the names will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you really should take a look at jQuery UI

1. [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)
2. [Dragable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)
3. [Dropable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

Comment: but can this be used with .append, right now I am creating "virtual" divs using .append to make the dragable divs, but so far it's not allowing the drag probably since they aren't part of the physical DOM?

Answer (score 0):

well your question is fairly vague, so i'll answer fairly vaguely, should be in the right direction tho

what I would try to do is use Jquery UI, and when you initialize the draggable, in your option function for dragstop, inspect the parent element of the div and make an ajax call with the data you need to send to the server and have on the parent divs a data attribute -> data_yourData="whateverIam"

```
dragstop(function(){
    ajax call -> send this $(this).parent().data("whateverDataYouNeedToSendToTheServer");
)};
```

obviously this is pseudocode-ish

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I am using Jquery, and I have gotten sortable to work for content within one div, but not moving it around within mutiple divs.  Thanks for this response, looks helpful! lol